# How to get recipients from Twilio group MMS?

Tags: twilio, mms

I want to build a Twilio app that can receive a group MMS and return a message back to the group. Is it possible to send and receive group MMS messages on Twilio? Also is it possible to retrieve all of the participant numbers in the group?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

Currently we only log the Twilio phone number that the message was sent to.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, its still true

Comment: apparently this is the place for twilio group mms feature requests.  @DevinRader is this still the case?

Comment: still the case.

Comment: 2019 and still the case?